# How can I convert a Python object type (supposed to be Python date type) column to a Python date column?

Tags: python, date

I have a column assigned for dates, which is presented in two formats: dd/mm/yyyy and also Excel format (eg: '43549'). I want the column type to be date in Python. How should I do it? The csv. file comes from joining together several Excel files. I already checked that the column has no NaN values.

I am really lost. I know that there are two Python libraries regarding this topic, which are xlrd and DateTime. Yet, I am having difficulties in implementing the code correctly.

```
xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(falso_df['Invoice Date'].any(),0)
```

TypeError:

`'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`

I expect to have a Python date type column with the dates following the dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: You should check your excel file, last time I got this error it was a typo in one of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas built in function 'pd.to_datetime(falso_df['Invoice Date'])'should work here.

Alternatively, when important an excel file into python, you can specify to infer datetime by setting `parse_dates =True` or designating which column(s) contain dates: `parse_dates =['Invoice Dates']`